# trying to edit uploaded form details using jsp

Tags: java, jquery, html, mysql, jsp

I have written program for upload file(s) using JSP and files uploads into MySQL database. There is one filelist.jsp page, it includes all the files uploaded by user and in this page all data will be fetched from database and it is successful. Now, I have added one extra column ("**Edit File**") in filelist.jsp page. When user will click on Edit option, form should be display with previous details and user will do changes as per need and will click on update. But I am getting different output. I have also attached **edit.jsp** page.

This is my edit.jsp page

```html
   
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Timestamp"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>edit Page</title>
        <style>
            tr,td,th{
                padding: 20px;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <br>
        <%
            Connection con = null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            
            
            %>
            
            <table border="2">
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 20%">Z ID</th>
                <th style="width: 20%">First Name</th>
                <th style="width: 20%">Last Name</th>
                <th style="width: 20%">Mail ID</th>
                <th style="width: 20%">Division</th>
                <th style="width: 20%">Department</th>
                <th style="width: 20%">Cost Center Code</th>
                <th style="width: 20%">Document No.</th>
                <th style="width: 20%">Document Name</th>
                
               
                <th style="width: 20%">Document Type</th>
                <th style="width: 20%">Document Category</th>
                <th style="width: 20%">Document Classification</th>
                <th style="width: 20%">Authorised By</th>
                <th style="width: 20%">Validity - From Date</th>
                <th style="width: 20%">Validity - To Date</th>
                <th style="width: 20%">Document Level</th>
                <th style="width: 20%">Document General(F31151)</th>
                <th style="width: 20%">Serial No.</th>
                
                <th style="width: 20%">Revision No.</th>
                <th style="width: 20%">Issuer</th>
                <th style="width: 20%">Status</th>
                <th style="width: 20%">File Name</th>
                <th style="width: 20%">File Path</th>
                <th style="width: 20%">Added Date</th>
                <th style="width: 20%">Download</th>
            </tr>
            <%
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dmsqms","root","");
                
                
                
                Statement stat = null;
                stat = con.createStatement();
                String u = request.getParameter("zid");
                
                String data = "select * from dmsfiles where zid = '"+u+"'";
                rs = stat.executeQuery(data);
                
                while(rs.next()){
                    
                
                
            %>
        
            
            <tr>
                <td><%=rs.getString(1)%></td>              
                <td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>           
                <td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>   
                <td><%=rs.getString(4)%></td> 
                <td><%=rs.getString(5)%></td> 
                <td><%=rs.getString(6)%></td> 
                <td><%=rs.getString(7)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(8)%></td>              
                <td><%=rs.getString(9)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(10)%></td>          
                <td><%=rs.getString(11)%></td> 
                <td><%=rs.getString(12)%></td>           
                <td><%=rs.getString(13)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(14)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(15)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(16)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(17)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(18)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(19)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(20)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(21)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(22)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(23)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(24)%></td>
                      
                <td><a href="DownloadServletClass?fileName=<%=rs.getString(22)%>">Download</a></td>
                  
            </tr>
            <%
                }
            %>    
        </table><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Update</button>
        <a href="index.jsp" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>
        
    </body>
</html>
<%
            String z_id = request.getParameter("zid");
            String first_Name = request.getParameter("firstname");
            String last_Name = request.getParameter("lastname");
            String mail_i_d = request.getParameter("mailid");
            String d_iv = request.getParameter("division");
            String de_pt = request.getParameter("department");
            String cost_centercode = request.getParameter("costcentercode");
            String doc_num = request.getParameter("documentnumber");                 //textbox value of documentnumber field
            String doc_Name = request.getParameter("documentname");
            String doc_Type = request.getParameter("Document_Type");                 //textbox value of Document_Type field
            String doc_Category = request.getParameter("Document_Category");   
            String doc_classification = request.getParameter("Document_Classification");
            String authorised_by = request.getParameter("authorisedby");
            String from_date = request.getParameter("fromdate");
            String to_date = request.getParameter("todate");
            
            String document_level = request.getParameter("documentlevel");
            String document_general = request.getParameter("documentgeneral");
            String serial_number = request.getParameter("serialnumber");
            String revision_number = request.getParameter("revisionnumber");
            String iss_uer = request.getParameter("issuer");
            String sta_tus = request.getParameter("status");
            String file_Name = "";
            String folder_Name = "allfiles";
            String pa_th = folder_Name + File.separator + file_Name;
            Timestamp add_ed_date = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
            
            if(z_id != null && first_Name != null && last_Name != null && mail_i_d != null && d_iv != null && de_pt != null && cost_centercode != null && doc_num != null && doc_Name != null && doc_Type != null && doc_Category != null && doc_classification != null && authorised_by != null && from_date != null && to_date != null && document_level != null && document_general != null && serial_number != null && revision_number != null && iss_uer != null && sta_tus != null && file_Name != null && folder_Name != null && pa_th != null && add_ed_date != null){
                String query = "update dmsfiles set zid=?,firstname=?,lastname=?,mailid=?,division=?,department=?,costcentercode=?,document_number=?,document_name=?,document_type=?,document_category=?,document_classification=?,authorised_by=?,fromdate=?,todate=?,document_level=?,document_general=?,serial_number=?,revision_number=?,issuer=?,status=?,filename=?,path=?,added_date=? where zid='"+z_id+"'";
                ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
                
                ps.setString(1,z_id);
                ps.setString(2,first_Name);
                ps.setString(3,last_Name);
                ps.setString(4,mail_i_d);
                ps.setString(5,d_iv);
                ps.setString(6,de_pt);
                ps.setString(7,cost_centercode);
                ps.setString(8,doc_num);
                ps.setString(9,doc_Name);
                ps.setString(10,doc_Type);
                ps.setString(11,doc_Category);
                ps.setString(12,doc_classification);
                ps.setString(13,authorised_by);
                ps.setString(14,from_date);
                ps.setString(15,to_date);
                ps.setString(16,document_level);
                ps.setString(17,document_general);
                ps.setString(18,serial_number);
                ps.setString(19,revision_number);
                ps.setString(20,iss_uer);
                ps.setString(21,sta_tus);
                ps.setString(22,file_Name);
                
                ps.setString(23,pa_th);
                ps.setTimestamp(24, null);
                ps.executeUpdate();
                response.sendRedirect("filelist.jsp");
                
                
                
                
                
            }
    
    

%>
```

I have done below changes into my filelist.jsp Page

```html
<th>Edit File</th>
```

```html
<td><a href='edit.jsp?zid=<%=rs.getString(1)%>' class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a></td>
```

This is output when i click on edit option for any row.

[image: This is the output when I click on edit option for any row]

Comment: I solved above error. now when i click on edit then form with existing details does not open.

Comment: post your `edit.jsp` as well

Comment: already posted edit.jsp

Comment: @Swati could you please check above code that I have posted?

Comment: what issue your currently facing can you elaborate it more ?

Comment: I have one index.jsp page where user will fill all the fields and details will be submit(also selected files will submit). I am successful till this point. I have one filelist.jsp page, in that all rows or records from mysql database has been fetched. I have added one column in filelist.jsp to "edit file". for each row, there is one separate edit option. when I click on edit option, then index.jsp page should open with previous stored details to do changes and should click on Update then the respective row details will be change in database & filelist.jsp.but I am getting different output.

Comment: Try to print `u` and see if it has required data or not .

Comment: actually I am referring this video. In this video please check last two min output. I was trying exactly same for my program. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_uLJfwFzkk

Comment: what does your url show when you are in your `edit.jsp` page ? does it shows required `zid` ?

Comment: @Swati I have added output above. Could you please check it? :)

Comment: yes i understood that already you are not getting any data . that's the reason i have asked you to check your variable `u` what it has in it . because your `select` query doesn't print required result.

Comment: I also don't know what that variable "u" is?? I had reffered from that you tube video ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207063/discussion-between-swati-and-priya-dhanba).

Comment: @Swati please help me to solve issue